# Determine All Day Event from Outlook 2010

Tags: php, outlook, fullcalendar, icalendar

I am trying to determine if my event is an all day event in my ICS file exported from Outlook 2010.

I have copied and pasted my file which contains 2 ALL Day Events... any thoughts would be appreciated.

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20110809T033932Z
DESCRIPTION:This will be my description for meeting with Justin\n
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20110809
DTSTAMP:20110809T040222Z
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20110808
LAST-MODIFIED:20110809T034001Z
LOCATION:At Starbucks
PRIORITY:5
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:Meet with Justin
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000403EC9560B56CC01000000000000000
    010000000C69C80C5784EBC418582D51931DC82EA
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//E
    N">\n<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="MS Exchange Server ve
    rsion 08.01.0240.003">\n<TITLE></TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY>\n<!-- Converted f
    rom text/rtf format -->\n\n<P DIR=LTR><SPAN LANG="en-us"><FONT FACE="Calib
    ri">This will be my description for meeting with Justin</FONT></SPAN><SPAN
     LANG="en-us"></SPAN></P>\n\n</BODY>\n</HTML>
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:FREE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-AUTOFILLLOCATION:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE:0
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20110809T040132Z
DESCRIPTION:ALL DAY DESCRIPTION\n
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20110810
DTSTAMP:20110809T040222Z
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20110809
LAST-MODIFIED:20110809T040159Z
LOCATION:ALL DAY LOCATION
PRIORITY:5
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:ALL DAY EVENT TITLE
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E0080000000080148F680E56CC01000000000000000
    01000000088619AAED47E4F43A2AC4420C15E7309
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//E
    N">\n<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="MS Exchange Server ve
    rsion 08.01.0240.003">\n<TITLE></TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY>\n<!-- Converted f
    rom text/rtf format -->\n\n<P DIR=LTR><SPAN LANG="en-us"><FONT FACE="Calib
    ri">ALL DAY DESCRIPTION</FONT></SPAN><SPAN LANG="en-us"></SPAN></P>\n\n</B
    ODY>\n</HTML>
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:FREE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-AUTOFILLLOCATION:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE:0
END:VEVENT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if NO time specified....if it is  DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20110808  it's an all day, but DTSTART can also
be:

DTSTART:19980118T073000Z
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:19980101T050000Z
DTSTART;TZID=Australia/Sydney:20080801T183000

It may have a DURATION and NOT an ENDDATE (should NOT Have both)

If it has an Enddate and the end date is midnight (start of day) and the DTSTART is also midnight (prev or earlier day) THEN it is conceptually also an allday in that timezone, (albeit two partial days in other timezones).

Agruably it should have been represented as VALUE=DATE, not VALUE=DATE-TIME. but what can one do, one has to deal with what comes up in the files.

Duration if it has something after the P, before the T, and nothing after the T, then it is also an allday

P1D
not:
PT15M

DTSTART:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.2.4

Durations:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.2.5

Answer (score 1):

See [previous discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716237/single-day-all-day-appointments-in-ics-files) on this topic. In general, the DTSTART is a date (no time) and DTEND is the next date (no time), so it is an all day event.